# Filemaker 10: Fill repeating fields with calculation

Tags: field, filemaker, repeat

I have a repeating field (say size 10) in my Filemaker database and try to fill it say with the Values 1..10.

I now want to use "Auto-Enter Calculation" to fill the field:

```
Case(
    RepField = 1; 1;
    RepField = 2; 2
)
```

But the field does not contain any values. How do I fill the field based on a calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An auto-entered calculation cannot set values in the other repetitions. You'd need to use a script trigger or a button to call a script to set the repetitions on record creation.